# Bricking up door/damp

Tags: concrete-block, damp-proof-course

I'm about to block up this doorway and have noticed damp in the bottom corner. If I were to lay a DPC between the screed and first layer of blocks, would that solve the issue....or is it going to require specialist attention?

[image]

This is how it looks from the outside, also evidence of damp I think:

[image]

This is an extension to the original house (about 10 years ago), midlands UK. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely maybe. Give us more info about the wall and floor material. Is it an interior or exterior door? What does it look like on the outside - are there places for water/moisture to get in from the outside? If so, you're just hiding the problem by sealing it in the wall instead of fixing the problem by preventing it from getting in there in the first place. Is this directly on the ground or is there a foundation below it? Where in the world are you?

Comment: Sorry @FreeMan have added some info

Comment: To make sure we understand, you are planning to remove the door, and install/repair the stucco and brick for weather proofing, besides filling in the interior wall?

Comment: Water sits on the stoop, rots the threshold and goes inside. Remove the door frame, the trim, and the stoop that juts out, until you're back to brick that you can lay two more rows of brick on, flush with the exterior. Then the stucco, however that was done, also flush with the exterior.

Comment: @Jack removing the door and replacing with blocks

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to remove the door and simply replace it with blocks, I would urge you to finish the outside like the existing walls are. Perhaps that is your plan all along but you did not specify that you were.

As mentioned in a comment, the floor slab that the door sets on needs to be broke back to the point that the face brick on the outside can pass in front of the slab. The existing brick need to be "toothed out" or raked back, since there are so few courses that the waterproofing layer (WPL) can be tied into with new material. The stucco needs to be carefully cut back too, or should be so the blockwork that serves as backing for the stucco can tied in to and expose the edges of the existing WPL to tie into that as well.

Then of course, lay up new brick that matches the original with the same mortar color and the necessary coats of stucco to build up and finish that the same to match existing as well.